# Are there any Python template engines that support Python 3.x

Tags: templates, python-3.x

It seems they all run on Python 2.x.

(Actually I want a more widely-used engine that has Python 3.x support.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file/78139684#78139684

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just released Jinja 2.3 has experimental support for Python 3. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/2/10/jinja-2-3-released

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using beta software, the newly-released moody-templates was written for Python 3 from the ground up.

https://github.com/etianen/moody-templates

Answer (score 1):

Maybe very outdated, but [Mako](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mako/0.4.0) supports python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The [**first search result**](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+templating) is [**the templating wiki page**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating); which includes at least one [**templating engine**](http://evoque.gizmojo.org/) which says it works on Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 **and 3.0**.