# Python 3 Template Engine

Tags: python, templates, python-3.x, template-engine

Is there a template engine for Python 3? It should be flexible (not HTML/XML centric) and fast.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217736/are-there-any-python-template-engine-that-supports-python-3-x

Comment: @MikeGraham It is _exactly_ that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Jinja](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/)

Comment: Jinja2's documentation says that Python 3 support is experimental and only covers >=3.3, http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#experimental-python-3-support.  The OP may be after an engine that is officially supported and stable under Python 3.2.x.

Comment: @JacobWan Note my answer is already more than 3 years old. At that time (experimentally) supported python was probably version 3.1. In the same link you point they recommend the previous jinja version 2.6 for py3.2.

Comment: My point was that Jinja 2's Python 3 support was and still is experimental.  Just a note for those coming to this page looking for information about templating engines with complete support for Python 3.

Comment: Jinja2 proved to be quite stable with Python3, but I have been using it on a small-scale base. You might will need some jogging to install a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Texthon is a Python-eval based template engine with a focus on generating readable code. 
http://texthon.chipsforbrain.org/
No prerequisites aside from Python. Texthon is primarily developed using Python 3.3, but it’s 2.7 compatible as well.

Answer (score 0):

[mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) is the template I use everyday (with python3) to generate C code. Flexible and not XML/HTML centric.