# Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?

Tags: python, decompiling, pyc, compiled

Is it possible to get some information out of the .pyc file that is generated from a .py file?

Answer (score 228):

### Intro

Python decompilation is a hard problem, particularly for recent 3.x versions.  That's why there are various tools, all with limitations and bugs.

However, Python 2.7 and earlier 3.x versions should work pretty well, and even partial decompilation is better than losing everything.

### Tools to try

[Uncompyle6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6) works, with some bugs, for Python up to 3.8, and works well for 2.7.

- **Recommended option** to start with as it's aiming to unify earlier forks and focusing on automated unit testing.
- The [uncompyle6 GitHub page](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) has more details.
- Works best for earlier 3.x versions, not best choice for 3.7+

If that doesn't work, it's probably best to try this next - particularly for Python 3.7+:

- [decompyle3](https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3) is a fork of Uncompyle6, from same author, that should work better for 3.7 and 3.8.
- **Note:** this `decompyle3` package is from the `rocky/decompile3` repo - different spelling but same thing

If you still have problems, check the `uncompyle6` and `decompyle3` READMEs which link to other tools that may work better for your code.

### Limitations

You can get your code back including variable names and doc strings, but without the comments.

Some code may not successfully decompile, particularly with unusual control flow, or more recent Python 3.x versions.  This is due to bugs in these decompilers where Python has changed its bytecode over time.

### Supporting recent Python versions

Neither `uncompyle6` or `decompyle3` support Python 3.9 or higher, and support for 3.7 or higher is limited.

New optimizations in Python are making decompilation harder, and both code contributions and sponsorship are lacking for both projects.

What you can do to help:

- Raise GitHub issues for these projects with bugs, after checking for similar issues - both run unit test suites on a range of Python versions.
- Sponsor these projects, particularly if they helped you

#### Preventing loss of code in future

Frequent Git commits or backups are clearly a good idea.

Some editors/IDEs have features to help recover deleted files even if not committed to Git. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657786/992887) for some pointers that may work in your editor or IDE, including VS Code and JetBrains IDEs such as PyCharm, GoLand and IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had accidentally deleted my .py file instead of .pyc. This saved me from having to rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: For those of you here because you accidentally deleted the wrong file, I _highly_ recommend source control!

Comment: ^ And if you're using PyCharm, you can right-click your file/folder in the Project pane and goto Local History > Show History to revert changes. Life saver.

Comment: `uncompyle6` is also available online at https://www.decompiler.com/

Comment: I've added a link to a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657786/992887) explaining how to undelete files in some editors and IDEs.

Comment: uncompyle6 does not support python 3.9 at the time of this comment.

Comment: @CodeMed - good point, I've done an update mentioning limitations in more recent Python 3.x versions.

Answer (score 38):

You may try ***[Easy Python Decompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/)***. It's based on Decompyle++ and Uncompyle2.
It's supports decompiling python versions 1.0-3.3

Note: I am the author of the above tool.

Comment: It does its job. Good work. BTW, did you write this tool in python?

Comment: Worked well for me (easy drag and drop). It's true that a linux distro would be nice, but its not all that hard opening a windows box.

Comment: Last release in 2015 and looks like it's closed source?

Comment: That link looks really safe.  Let me click it.

Comment: “SourceForge are (sic) abusing the trust that we and our users had put into their service in the past,” according to the GIMP project. Since 2013, SourceForge has been bundling junkware along with their installers — sometimes without a developer's permission. Don't download software from SourceForge if you can help it.

Comment: @MacGyver Sorry but these days you can't a trust link sourceforge or not, even it's a well known domain. The answer is from 2014 when https wasn't mandatory. Yes sourceforge track record has indeed gone south and I had stopped using sourceforge a long time ago.

Comment: No worries.  Not discrediting you.  I just didn't want others to get trojens, malware, spyware, viruses, or any other internet misdemeanors.  :)

Comment: Invalid pyc/pyo file - Magic value mismatch!?

Comment: @тнαтҩυιεткιᴅϟ The tool doesn't support modern Python versions. Try using an alternative.

Answer (score 33):

**Yes**.

I use [uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) decompile (even support latest Python 3.8.0):

`uncompyle6 utils.cpython-38.pyc > utils.py`

and the origin python and decompiled python comparing look like this:

[image: pyc uncompile utils]

so you can see, **ALMOST** same, decompile effect is **VERY GOOD**.

Comment: same experience here. `uncompyle6` is incredible.

Comment: At the time of writing does not support > 3.9 Python :(

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can get it with `unpyclib` that can be found on *pypi*.

```
$ pip install unpyclib
```

Than you can decompile your .pyc file

```
$ python -m unpyclib.application -Dq path/to/file.pyc
```

Comment: I tried this and it crashed with an exception, on quite a small file with no complex code (Django settings.py) - uncompyle2 worked fine instead.  -1 for that reason.

Comment: It crashed in Python 3.6 in lib\site-packages\unpyclib\applcation.py with `print __copyright` -- why is it using the Python 2.7 version of `print` without parenthesis?

Comment: @DavidChing `unpyclib`'s first and last release [was in 2009](https://pypi.org/project/unpyclib/#history), safe to say it's a Python 2 only program.

Answer (score 16):

Decompyle++ (pycdc) was the only one that worked for me: https://github.com/zrax/pycdc

was suggested in [Decompile Python 2.7 .pyc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189352/decompile-python-2-7-pyc/10047631#10047631)

Comment: And this worked for me for code that was compiled with Python 2.6!

Answer (score 6):

I've been at this for a couple hours and finally have a solution using Decompyle++:

- visit `https://cmake.org/download/` and install CMake.
- visit `https://github.com/zrax/pycdc` and grab a copy of this repo: `pycdc-master`.
- add `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin` to your system environment variables under PATH.

I suggest putting your `pycdc-master` folder into another folder, like `anotherFolder`.

Now you can run these commands in the command line:

- `cd anotherFolder` to go into the folder that has `pycdc-master` in it.
- `cmake pycdc-master`
- `cd ../` to go up one directory,
- then: `cmake --build anotherFolder`

`pycdc.exe` will then be in `anotherFolder\Debug`.

Do something like `pycdc.exe onlyhopeofgettingmycodeback.pyc` in a console and it will print out the source code. I had Python 3.9.6 source code and nothing else was working.

Comment: Usually you create the `build` folder inside the repo and then inside the `build` folder you call `cmake ..`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

There is a perfect open-source Python (.PYC) decompiler, called Decompyle++ https://github.com/zrax/pycdc/

Decompyle++ aims to translate compiled Python byte-code back into valid and human-readable Python source code. 
While other projects have achieved this with varied success, Decompyle++ is unique in that it seeks to support byte-code from any version of Python.

Comment: While pycdc is good, it is not perfect. If you look at https://github.com/zrax/pycdc/issues there are over 50 individual types of problems it has in decompilation. This is however spread over the 16 or so releases of python, and both the language and code has changed drastically. It may be that for the things you have tried you haven't been able to find a problem. However, in my opinion, to classify something as "perfect", one would have to take say the entire Python library for each version, decompile it, and have it pass its own tests properly. No decompiler can do that yet.

Answer (score 3):

Install using 
pip install pycompyle6

pycompyle6 filename.pyc

Answer (score 0):

---

**Title:** Extracting Files from PyInstaller-Generated Executable

**Problem:**

How can I extract files from an executable created by PyInstaller?

**Solution:**

1. Clone the [pyinstxtractor-ng](https://github.com/pyinstxtractor/pyinstxtractor-ng) repository:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/pyinstxtractor/pyinstxtractor-ng.git
   ```
2. Extract the executable:

   ```bash
   cd pyinstxtractor-ng
   python pyinstxtractor-ng.py "<path_to_/dist/app>"
   ```
3. Install dependencies:

   ```bash
   sudo yum install cmake make clang
   ```
4. Clone the [pycdc](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc) repository:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git
   ```
5. Build and compile:

   ```bash
   cd pycdc
   cmake CMakeLists.txt
   make
   ```
6. Decompile the bytecode:

   ```bash
   ./pycdc "<path_to_/app_extracted/app.pyc>"
   ```

By following these steps, you can extract and decompile files from a PyInstaller-generated executable.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to decompile a pyc but have python 3.9 installed you can force uncompyle6 to run. It's not perfect but it does work. Just edit **site-packages\uncompyle6\bin\uncompile.py**

```
def main_bin():
if not (sys.version_info[0:2] in ((2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 0),
                                  (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
                                  (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
                                  (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)
```

Just add the version you have installed in the same format as the others and save. It will at least run.

Comment: It does not decompile pyc made with python3.9

Comment: At the time of writing does not support > 3.9 Python :( you can _force_ it to run, but will not perform, sadly.