# Cythonize a .pyc no .pyx available

Tags: python, dll, compilation, cython

In my hands i have a .pyc and not the corresponding .py or .pyx.

- Is it possible to cythonize a .pyc ?
- should it be decompressed to .py first and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cython is a superset of Python, and hence you can cythonize a `.py` file. I say this because `.pyc` files can be decompiled to `.py` file. There are several libraries that can do this, however, I would suggest that you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189352/decompile-python-2-7-pyc) asked previously.

Although this *can* be done, there are no real benefits, your python code can at most gain a 20% speed boost.

Comment: thanks. there is no benefit to decompile the pyc to py but there is one gain in speed when i cythonize to C++, right ?

Comment: No, you will not gain any speed. I can explain further, but it will only confuse you. Unless you statically define the types for your data, Cython can do very little optimization. It says so in the [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html).

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html confirms "pure Python scripts can be compiled with Cython, it usually results only in a speed gain of about 20%-50%." but further explains how to add type annotations in a separate `pxd` file, gaining more speed while keeping a plain `.py` source