# I am looking for a way to get a .pyc file to a .py file

Tags: python

I currently have a python file that is in the .pyc format, so i can only run it.  I have looked up ways to decompile the file but none seem to work with the version of python i am using (3.4.1).  I am looking to get it into .py so i can edit the program in the shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189352/decompile-python-2-7-pyc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file?lq=1

Comment: Does it a exist a `unpyclib` version for Python 3.4?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what that is.