# Decompile *.pyc file

Tags: python, decompiler, pyc

I'm a newcomer to programming, and currently taking a course on MIT OCW, using Python 2.6.

The site provides me with a .pyc file, and I wonder if it can be decompiled back to a .py file.

I have researched some ways on the Internet, such as this: [Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

But I just can't understand what they're saying (newcomer).

It would be a great help for newcomers like me if there is a detailed guide on how-to-do this.

Thank you, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the post, I'm just newcomer and need to know what they are saying in that post. Besides my file is 49KBs so I cannot use online method.

Comment: If you have a specific question about the answers in that post maybe it can be answered. Otherwise I don't know what you expect here. BTW I doubt decompiling will actually help you, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe I'm a newcomer but reading code, especially well-structured one is easy though. But thanks, I just expect for a more detailed instruction on this.

Comment: The result of decompiling will be pretty far away from well-structured, easy-to-read code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this tools might help you.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/unpyc/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but can you show me how to use the program?

Comment: Read the documentation on the website / inside file...