# Exe to python with pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

So I made a huge mistake and deleted my code file (python). The only thing I have is my python file as .exe that I created with pyinstaller. Is there a way to reverse this and to extract my code file from .exe?

Comment: Is it a single-file executable (created with the `--one-file` option)?

Comment: yes, its is. -F -w

Comment: Try opening the executable with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), do you find something inside?

Comment: Cannot open file as archive :(

Comment: Not necessary in this case, but there are data recovery programs to retrieve files cleared from the Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can extract the contents of the `.exe` file using [PyInstaller Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/). Run it like this:

```
python pyinstxtractor.py executable.exe
```

You will then get a bunch of files, including your original python file.

Comment: That kinda worked, just the problem is now, that I dont have my original python file and the CMD says I can now use a python decompiler on pyc files. Where can I find one for python 3.x?

Comment: Are you sure your source file wasn't extracted? In my case, it was there but without the `.py` extension.

Comment: Oh god, I re-checked everything and I found it! While I'm still intrested if there are any 3.x pythong decompilers (because I was unable to find one myself) you still saved my life.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I honestly don't know much about `pyc` to `py` decompilers, but I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file) may be of help.

Comment: sorry, for my interrupt, actually, I extracted .exe using pyinstxtractor.py and I got extracted foler.
So do you mean this folder include some *.py files?
I hope you reply for me.
Regards.

Comment: Hi, @Mantas Kandratavicius and Zenadix. Unfortunately, my extracted folder has no python files(.py files). Could you explain how I should do now? Regards!