# python compilation-encryption to skip plagiarism

Tags: python, compilation, source-code-protection

I'm considering to compile a python code in order to ensure the source-code without losing script functionality

By reading the following post from stackoverflow: "[Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file[1])", I took into account that there is still a chance to get the source code by decompiling the .pyc file.

So, **the question** is:

Is there anyway to **lock** and **protect the code** to get a compiled program in order to protect the code of the script(.py)?

Comment: Please @Aaron add, further aspects and limitations in order substantiate your answer. Because, as far as I know im not wondering nothing impossible... Thx

Comment: @Aaron could you specify/explain why is ther not any possibility?

Comment: you already provided an answer to your own question... the python interpreter only interprets regular python bytecode, which as you have shown can be decompiled

Comment: depending on how technical you want to get, everything can be decompiled with enough work, but things like reading raw x86 binary is a lot harder than python bytecode

Comment: a workaround could be to compile your sensitive functions that you don't want others to easily reverse engineer in something like c++ or c# and add them as extension modules. this would make it much harder to reverse, but not impossible. This also limits portability which is one of python's main benefits

Comment: So, there was a misunderstanding, with the concept of lock the compilation I meant encryption. my apologies

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://github.com/Falldog/pyconcrete

Comment: whoever must execute the code must be able to decrypt it to run it....

Comment: @PeCaDe I poked around `pyconcrete` for a bit, and tried installing it.. (it won't install on my computer rn because I don't have mingw or the admin to install it). From an initial look it should be secure enough to prevent decompilation from anyone with less than a few years of solid experience.