# How to convert text/x-python to plain text format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a file with MIME type of `text/x-python`. It shows binary format when I opened it with Vim.

[image]

The file begins with these bytes, according to a hexdump with `xxd`:

```
00000000: 03f3 0d0a f0db af5a 6300 0000 0000 0000  .......Zc.......
00000010: 000e 0000 0040 6001 0073 2f0b 0000 6400  .....@`..s/...d.
```

How to convert this file into text format?

Comment: It should be just text. Can you post a sample of what you're looking at? (for example as output from `xxd` so we can see what the binary is)

Comment: Hi, @viraptor, thanks very much for your reply! I've uploaded an image. Please have a check.

Comment: We can't learn much from it - can you post the beginning of `xxd < model_train.py` instead? This will show us the contents in format we can actually analyse.

Comment: Could this be a pyc file with the wrong extension?

Comment: @viraptor, I've uploaded the picture. Thanks a lot. I think this file is a binary file, but from the `Readme` file in the project that contains this file, this file can be executed by `python model_train.py`. If this is a binary file, I'm not sure if python can execute binary file.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks for your reply. I also think this is a binary file. The author of this file may want to hide the source code.

Comment: perhaps there is some preamble in the file indicative of its real type?

Comment: Hi @PaulRooney, thanks for your reply. But I'm not sure how to get the extra information of this file. In fact, this file is included in a docker image. I just copy this file from the docker container to my host computer.

Comment: Indeed, now that the OP included a hexdump, we can see that this file begins with the bytes 0x03f30d0a, which the `file` tool identifies as byte-compiled code for Python 2.7.

Comment: @RJHunter, got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIME type `text/x-python`, and the file extension `.py`, are usually attached to plain-text files.

The file in your question is binary, not plain text, and so neither the file extension `.py` nor the MIME type `text/python` are appropriate. In other words: **the file has a misleading name.**

The bytes shown in the hexdump correspond to *compiled* Python bytecode. Files like these are usually named with `.pyc` instead of `.py`. When the Python interpreter loads a module from a `.py` text file, it compiles the text into bytecode saves a copy of the compiled result in a `.pyc` file. This means that loading is faster next time.

If you have `.pyc` bytecode but not the original `.py`, there are tools to disassemble ("decompile") the bytecode and show the results in Python text, but that's quite unusual situation.

See also: [Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

Comment: Hi, @RJHunter, thanks a lot for your kind answer! I also think this is binary file. But from the `Readme` file of the project that contains this file, it shows this file can be executed by `python model_train.py`. The author may make the content private, but the results of this file public.

Comment: The author may try to make the content of their file private, but like everything else in Python, you really can't do that unless you write an extension. I had a customer that tried obfuscating their code as a pyx file because they were supposed to share everything pertaining to the task as part of our agreement. I didn't even bother complaining, just spent 15 minutes researching decompilers. I got their code in plain text, and they got to keep their sense of smug security.

Comment: Hi, @MadPhysicist, thanks for your kind comment! Yeah, the author may convert the source code to binary code due to their agreement.