# Recover overwritten .py file overwitten using Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, recovery, file-recovery

I know I should have used version control but I have accidentally overwritten a script (.py file) by saving another script with exactly the same name while using Spyder.

Is there any way at all this can be recovered?

Answer (score 0):

Once the file has been compiled to a pyc it is lost. If you still have the old pyc file you may be able to decompile it:

[Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

Comment: Yeah I don't have a pyc file since it wasn't imported. Seems it's a goner..

Comment: Well, depending on how recent it was there might be a recoverable file in the caches of your OS, or a prograv that you've used to view it.