# Dev has vanished all i have left is a .pyt file how do I see source code?

Tags: python, decode, bytecode, decompiling, deobfuscation

Is there anyway to get source code back from a .pyt file? when I try to open all i get is a bunch of symbols. I had an .exe file then converted files to .pyc but the main source code seems to be in .pyt although this is me assuming as the file name was "FILE", but when reading through you can see it has the file name of .pyt in the source code.

I tried using online tools to decode but no luck.

Example of what i get:

```
c           @   sG  d  d l  Z  d  d l Z d  d l Z d  d l Z d  d l m Z d  d l m Z d  d l m Z d  d l    Z   d  d l
 m Z d  d l m
 Z
 d  d l m Z d  d l Z d  d l Z d  d l Z d  d l m Z d  d l m Z d  d    l m Z d  d
 l m Z d a d a e a e a e a d a d
 Z d Z e     j ƒ  a  e   j ƒ  a! e   j ƒ  a" d „  Z# d „  Z$ d „  Z% d „  Z& d „  Z' d „  Z( d „  Z) d „  Z* d „  Z+ d „  Z, d „  Z- d „  Z. d „  Z/ d „  Z0 d „  Z1 d „  Z2 d „  Z3 d  „  Z4 d! „  Z5 d" „  Z6 d# „  Z7 d$ „  Z8 d% „  Z9 e: d& k rCe   j; ƒ  e5 ƒ  n  d S('   iÿÿÿÿN(   t    UserAgent(   t   randint(   t   sleep(   t   ThreadPoolExecutor(   t   partial(   t   captcha(   t
   twitchAuth(   t   auth(   t   proxiesi    t   unlinks     _____
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

Comment: hello, no i wish it were as I found that solution. this file is a PYT and i just cant seem to get the raw data from it, just a bunch of symbols

Comment: Can you please provide a hexdump instead of the raw data of that portion of the file? It would be more readable.

Comment: Is this .pyt file in any way related to ESRI ArcGIS?

Comment: I have never used this library before but I came across this library which may help https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6

Comment: Are you sure, this is the source Code? Usually .pyt files are toolboxes in python

Comment: when using uncompyle6, i get some PYC files which i have converted to .py, however, this file is sitting in the main extracted directory with no extention type, but i know its the main part of the code. i change the extension to .py/pyc/pyt and all i get are symbols as above.

Comment: hexdump please.