# How do i get the py file from this?

Tags: python, pyc

I have decompiled a `.exe` compiled.
I got a `.pyz` file and some other files:

[image]

Extracted them and got this:

[image]

How am I able to get the `.py` file from all those `.pyc` files?

Comment: Seems like a Reverse Engineering question, already has an answer in [Reverse Engineering Stack Beta](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1702)

Answer (score 0):

You can decompile `.pyc` files yes - see these similar questions:

[Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/decompiling-pyc-files

**The short of it is that you can use a tool to generate `.py` files from `.pyc`:
https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/**

Comment: That's for 1 pyc but how about all of them? btw getting this for 1 file http://prntscr.com/nulugs

Comment: You would run the tool against each bytecode file. The original source likely had a number of python modules in it, so your decompiled source will have at least one file for each module.  Many commercial app distributors will take steps to prevent rebuilding the original source though, so you may not be able to parse the `.pyc` files you have. Check out the other answers linked for some more info.

Comment: So there's no way to get the source code? With Easy Python Decompiler im getting Invalid pyc/pyo file - Magic value mismatch!