# How can I execute code received from dis.dis() python?

Tags: python

How can I execute code received from dis.dis() python?

```
import dis
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
dis.dis(A)
'''It returns:
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
'''
```

I want something like this:

```
import dis
dis.run('''
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
''')
```

i.e. Execute python disassembler.(I can execute .pyc from python ,can i execute disassembler?)

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm just interested in "how does python work?" and I wanna try to write python disassembler and run it for better understanding of "how does python work?" 
**P.S** Don't laugh!:)

Comment: You can't. dis.dis just gives you a human readable version of the assembly code. If you want to understand it below the hood I'd recommend directly learning asm or c.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file

Comment: `dis`, as has been mentioned, produces output intended for human consumption.  There are other modules that produce disassembly intended to be modified and reassembled into a function: `byteplay` is the one I'm familiar with.  Note that there are several versions of this module out there, each supporting only specific Python versions, since the bytecode language tends to change fairly often.

Comment: @jasonharper byteplay doesn't seem to work on python 3.8.