# How to decompile Python 3.8.3 file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I deleted one of my python 3.8.3 scripts , but I still have scripts's .pyc file.
I tried using uncompyle6 but I'm always getting parsing errors.
Does anyone know how I can fix it?
If it helps I used the following modules: time, bs4, requests, re, pyautogui

Thanks very much.

Here is my error:
Click on the link for the full message: https://justpaste.it/6nrzc

```
# file olx.pyc
# Deparsing stopped due to parse error
```

Comment: try https://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file)

Comment: Only Python 3.4 is supported, I'm kn 3.8... Thanks.