# Main Python File Using Another Python File (I Want To Convert To .exe)

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I Created a Program That Has 2 `.py files`.
I Want To Make The Program a `.exe` file, I do it using `cx_Freeze`.
My Problem Is That I Convert The `main.py` To `.exe` but The Second Python File Is Still a `.py` File.
I Don't Want It Be a `.py` Because If It Is The User Can See The Code.
If I Also Convert The Second Python File The Program Doesn't Work Because I `import` The Python File In The Main File.
Any Suggestions?
**(I Don't Want To Copy The Second Python File To The Main Python File)**

Comment: In this case, perhaps you can compile the `py` file. I have used `Cython` before, but I am not sure if it will be decompiled.

Answer (score 1):

You are chasing the wrong rabbit here. The various tools that generate executable files from Python code are not compilers. They are just tools that embed a Python interpretor with py (or pyc) files to allow users to use the program without a prior Python installation.

Said differently you should not use them to hide your code (except from people not knowing a lot of Python): a pyc does not contain text code but according to the answers to [Is it possible to decompile a compiled .pyc file into a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5287253/3545273) , tools exists that convert back a pyc file into a py file (of course except the comments).

IMHO, you should better google for *python obfuscate* to find tools dedicated to obfuscation, what neither `cx-freeze` nor `pyinstaller` are.

BTW while there are appropriate use cases for obfuscation you should be aware that a determinate attacker can always circumvent it. The reason why the real protection for intellectual property is law and not technics...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how  two or more `.py` files can be converted to `.exe`.

But in python the easiest way to convert to .exe is a module named ***pyinstaller*** .

You can install it using  command `pip install pyinstaller` can get it . After just go to the directory where your project files are and open command prompt in that directory and execute `pyinstaller file_name`

Comment: pyinstaller gives .exe files that the computer detects as virus.

Comment: Yes if u send it to your friends it will show like that . Windows defends it all