# Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x83' in file <> on line 5, but no encoding declared

Tags: python

This is the code, I used "python -OO -m py_compile <filename.py>" to compile it and gave it to one of my friends. One of them got this error and the other ran it just fine. I also turned the file from pyc to py. What is causing the issue?

````py
import os
import requests
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
from tqdm import trange
def SendMsg(webhook, payload):
    return requests.post(webhook, json=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) 
def fun():
    option = input("Do you want webhook delete or checker\n(1)Deleter\n(2)Checker\n(3)Credits\n:")
    os.system('cls')
    if option == "1":
        webhook = input("Enter the webhook: ")
        os.system('cls')
        result = requests.delete(webhook)
        for i in trange(100, ascii=False, ncols=75, desc="- Analyzing"):
                sleep(0.01)
        time.sleep(.5)
        os.system('cls ')
        try:
            if 200 <= result.status_code < 300:
                print(f"Webhook deleted!")
            else:
                print(f"{result.status_code}, response:\n{result.json()}")
        except: print("Invalid Webhook smh")
    elif option == "2":
        webhook = input("Enter the webhook: ")
        os.system('cls')
        for i in trange(100, ascii=False, ncols=75, desc="- Analyzing"):
                sleep(0.01)
        time.sleep(.5)
        os.system('cls')
        epic = requests.get(webhook).json()
        name = epic['name']
        id = epic['id']
        channel_id = epic['channel_id']
        guild_id = epic['guild_id']
        avatar = epic['avatar']
        print(f"Name: {name}") 
        print(f"Avatar: {avatar}") 
        print(f"Id: {id}")
        print(f"Channel id: {channel_id}")
        print(f"Guild id: {guild_id}")
    elif option == "3":
        print("Credits")
    else:
        print("I can only do those 2 options")
    input("Press enter to close")
    os.system('cls')
    fun()
fun()```
````

Comment: How are your friends running the file you sent them? What was your rationale behind sending a pyc file rather than just the Python source?

Comment: I don't want them being able to change credit on who made it. They are using cmd

Comment: "using cmd" how? Which executable are they invoking? With what parameters? Remember that they can always put the pyc file through something like the tools discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file).

Comment: They are simply doing "python <filename.py>" not a exe

Comment: He also mentioned he did not mess with the file in anyway

Comment: It's likely that one of them picked a webhook that has non-ASCII characters in the name or avatar.  You'd need to know which line triggered that error.

Comment: it does not open at all, so the problem isn't the webhook

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.