# On Python 3.9 + how do I decompile pyc to py?

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3.9, I want to decompile a PYC file. I tried decompyle3, uncompyle6, but the outcome was as follows:

Decompyle3 requires Python 3.7-3.8, which is not available.
What should I do?

is there any way to do this!
I was able to get this for 3.8 but this isn't working for 3.9 or above.

Comment: Wait for Updates, this isn't available yet!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file/78139684#78139684